# Loading a JavaScript file using both defer and async

Tags: javascript

What would be the loading order of these two JavaScripts?

```
<script src="a.js">
<script src="b.js" defer async>
```

What happens to **b.js** that has both **defer** and **async**?

Comment: "If you specify both, async takes precedence on modern browsers, while older browsers that support defer but not async will fallback to defer." Source: https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-async-defer/

Answer (score 2):

As specified here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

**Async** is a Boolean attribute indicating that the browser should, if possible, load the script asynchronously.

While **Defer** is a Boolean attribute that indicates to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed, but before firing DOMContentLoaded.

So in your case, b.js would load after a.js